# ddslick dropdown json data with asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jquery

I searched the site but couldn't find what I exactly looking for. Then I end up with asking a question. My problem is I can't fill the ddslick dropdown with the json data from asp.net c# webmethod.The dropdown list appears with the default value.But when I click the dropdown in order to see other options, nothing happens.I can't fill the data to dropdown I think.
Here is my codes. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
[image: Combo is not opening]

```
public class ComboBox
{
     private bool _selected = false;
     public ComboBox()
     {
     }
     public string text { get; set; }
     public string value { get; set; }
     public bool selected
     {
          get { return _selected; }
          set { _selected = value; }
     }
     public string description{ get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetVehicleComboData()
{
  SqlToolkit mySqlKit = new SqlToolkit();
  mySqlKit.DoConnect();
  DataTable dt = mySqlKit.DoDTstr("Select VehicleTypeId, VehicleTypeName, VehicleTypeInfo from TBLVEHICLETYPES UNION ALL select '0','Lütfen Araç Tipi Seçiniz','' Order by VehicleTypeId ");
  List<ComboBox> comboData = new List<ComboBox>();
  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  { 
    ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.text = dr["VehicleTypeName"].ToString();
    combo.value = dr["VehicleTypeId"].ToString();
    combo.description = dr["VehicleTypeInfo"].ToString();
    comboData.Add(combo);
  }
  var jsonForVehicles = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comboData, Formatting.Indented);
  mySqlKit.DoDisconnect();
  return jsonForVehicles;
}
```

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({   
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'CreateOffer.aspx/GetVehicleComboData',
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (myData) {
        $('#demoTruncated').ddslick({
                data : myData,
                selectText: "Select a vehicle type",
                truncateDescription: true,
                onSelected: function (data) {
                    //callback function: do something with selectedData;
                    alert(data.selectedIndex);
                    displaySelectedData("5: Dropdown with truncated description", data);
                }
            });
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
</script>
```

I debug the javascript with firebug and I saw that myData object coming from server side is like below. I can only see one object. But there must be 4 objects, I think. Because I have 4 records to be seen on dropdown list.

myData :
    Object { d="[\r\n {\r\n "text": "Lü...ription": "de4"\r\n }\r\n]"}

d :
    "[ { "text": "Lütfen Araç Tipi Seçiniz", "value": "0", "selected": false, "description": "" }, { "text": "Tenteli Tır", "value": "1", "selected": false, "description": "de1" }, { "text": "Kapalı Kasa Tır", "value": "2", "selected": false, "description": "de2" }, { "text": "Kamyon Römork Tır ", "value": "3", "selected": false, "description": "de3" }, { "text": "Kamyon", "value": "4", "selected": false, "description": "de4" } ]"

Comment: Anyone has an idea about where am I wrong?

Comment: Any help is appreciated on the above problem.

Comment: Seems like noone has faced a problem like me.